# Pulumi invalid network configuration for bridge mode ECS service

Tags: amazon-ecs, pulumi

I'm trying to create an ECS Service using Pulumi with task with network mode `bridge` in order to run multiple tasks on an instance.

When creating the service, pulumi outputs `error: Plan apply failed: InvalidParameterException: Network Configuration is not valid for the given networkMode of this task definition.` which is not valid.

It seems pulumi provides a `networkConfiguration` even though this is not permitted when the network mode is `bridge`:

```
    [urn=urn:pulumi:dev::pulumi::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::pulumi-dev]
        + aws:ecs/service:Service: (create)
            [urn=urn:pulumi:dev::pulumi::awsx:x:ecs:EC2Service$aws:ecs/service:Service::test]
            cluster                        : "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:131009595785:cluster/test-12196f9"
            deploymentMaximumPercent       : 200
            deploymentMinimumHealthyPercent: 100
            desiredCount                   : 2
            enableEcsManagedTags           : false
            launchType                     : "EC2"
            loadBalancers                  : [
                [0]: {
                    containerName : "backend"
                    containerPort : 3000
                    targetGroupArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:131009595785:targetgroup/57d096ee-73ab93e/fce1408d3c067066"
                }
            ]
            name                           : "test-3e870ec"
            networkConfiguration           : {
                assignPublicIp: false
                securityGroups: [
                    [0]: "sg-035513ef294414b65"
                ]
                subnets       : [
                    [0]: "subnet-08831ff5642406fc7"
                    [1]: "subnet-00e3e870707b6aa90"
                ]
            }
            schedulingStrategy             : "REPLICA"
            taskDefinition                 : "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:131009595785:task-definition/test-aece9bcd:24"
            waitForSteadyState             : true
```

Is there a way to avoid setting the networkConfiguration? I can set `securityGroups` and `subnets` of the service to `[]` but there is no way to set `assignPublicIp`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was not yet supported by pulumi but was fixed in [PR 233](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx/pull/232) with [this change](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx/commit/a6dc97ce73f53bd099179f4557692b12710bd8cb#diff-f03268642707ddc3d64969e74f469191R89).

The fix is included in [pulumi-awsx 0.18.2](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx/releases/tag/v0.18.2).

A `networkConfiguration` is now only specified for network mode `awsvpc`.